# Angular JS ng-init not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am absolutely new to angular js. I am trying to build a simple app. I am testing the site on wamp server. For some reason, the ng-init directive isn't working. Could anyone please help? Also, angular material elements are not displaying. Code is below:

```
<body ng-app="ngTest" ng-init="message='Hello'">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
```

Upon running all that is showing is:

```
<body ng-app="ngTest" ng-init="message='Hello'">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
```

Comment: Open console and read the error.

Comment: Can you show the console errors...

Comment: Thanks! it did solve the problem. But how do I get angular material components to show up? Like buttons. They aren't showing.

Comment: Remove your application name, like ng-app=""  it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both the application (via ng-app) as well as the controller (via "ng-controller"). You also need to include the js files for AngularJS as well as the JS file containing your declaration of your control (via the scripts section).